# Name for an involution associated to a Coxeter element

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, terminology, coxeter-groups, weyl-group

Let $(W,S)$ be a finite Coxeter system, and $c \in W$ a Coxeter element.

There is an involution $g\in W$ for which the involutive map $w \mapsto gw^{-1}g$ fixes $c$. Is there a standard name for this involution (which obviously depends on the choice of $c$)?

How to see there is such an involution: first assume $c=c_Lc_R$ is *bipartite*, i.e., $L$ and $R$ are a bipartition of the Coxeter diagram (possible of course because the diagram is a tree), and $c_L$ (resp. $c_R$) is the product of all simple reflections in $L$ (resp. in $R$). Then $g=c_L$ gives such an involution. But all Coxeter elements are conjugate, so we can conjugate $c$ to any $c'$ we want, and then $g$ will conjugate to the appropriate $g'$.

Speaking of conjugates, it's easy to see that if $g$ is such an involution, then $c^{r}gc^{-r}$ is also such an involution for any $r$. So I guess I'm really looking for a name for this $\langle c \rangle$-conjugacy class of involutions.

Why I care: for such an involution $g$, it's easily seen that the map $w\mapsto g w^{-1} g$ gives an involutive automorphism of the interval $[e,c]_{\mathrm{abs}}$ between the identity $e$ and $c$ in [absolute order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group#Partial_orders) on $W$. This interval is often called the *lattice of $W$-noncrossing partitions* and has nice properties (it features heavily in Coxeter-Catalan combinatorics).

**EDIT**: Since in the comments it was asked whether $g$ was determined up to $\langle c \rangle$-conjugacy, let me address that.

Suppose $g, h\in W$ are both involutions with $gc^{-1}g=c=hc^{-1}h$. Then $ghchg=c$, so $gh$ commutes with $c$. But it's well-known that the centralizer of $c$ is $\langle c \rangle$, so $gh=c^{r}$ for some $r$.

Conversely, if $g$ is an involution with $gc^{-1}g=c$, then setting $h := c^{r}g$, it is also easily seen that we have $h^2=1$ and $hc^{-1}h=c$.

So actually, $g$ is not determined up to $\langle c \rangle$-conjugacy; rather the (potentially larger) coset $\langle c \rangle g = g\langle c \rangle$ is the set of involutions satisfying this condition. (I think whether this coset really is larger than the $\langle c\rangle$-conjugacy class of $g$ has to do with the parity of the Coxeter number $h$.)

**EDIT2**:

As LSpice notes in the comments, we can say more precisely that:

- the set of elements of $W$ which conjugate $c$ to its inverse form some $\langle c\rangle$-coset $g\langle c \rangle = \langle c \rangle g$;
- all of these elements are necessarily involutions.

**EDIT3**:

I recently learned that discussion of this business occurs in Sections 3.4.6 and 4.3.4 of https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611106 (Drew Armstrong, "Generalized Noncrossing Partitions and Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups
"). Still, no conclusive terminology is given.

Comment: Is the $\langle c\rangle$-conjugacy class of $g$ determined by your condition?

Comment: For bipartite Coxeter elements, this is the "bipartite belt" in cluster theory, see Section 8 of Fomin, Zelevinsky - Cluster Algebras IV: Coefficients.

Comment: Observe also that every Coxeter element is bipartite for some choice of simple system and your general involution $g$ is $c_L$ for that choice of simple system.

Comment: @ChristianStump: The notion of bipartite belt seems related, but I don't think they're exactly the same. For example, what I'm talking about is an involution. Whereas, quoting Fomin and Zelevinsky, "To rephrase Theorem 8.8: the bipartite belt (or the associated Y -system) is periodic if and only if the Cartan matrix A is of finite type; if it is periodic, then 2(h+2) is a period; if it is not, then all cluster variables on the bipartite belt are distinct, as are all Laurent polynomials in the associated Y -system."

Comment: @LSpice: I thought about your question, and it made me realize $g$ is not determined up to $\langle c \rangle$-conjugacy; rather the whole coset $\langle c \rangle g = g \langle c \rangle$ satisfies this condition. See the edit.

Comment: I agree that $g\langle c\rangle$ being related to the $\langle c\rangle$-orbit of $g$ depends on the Coxeter number $h$.  In fact, the orbit is clearly $g\langle c^2\rangle$, so they are equal if and only if $h$ is odd. (But you might not want also to use $h$ for the name of your other element satisfying this condition!)  Note that your argument doesn't really use that $g$ is an involution ($g_i$ both work implies $g_1 g_2^{-1} \in \langle c\rangle$), so $g$ being an involution is a deduced *property*, not part of its definition, which is not at all obvious to me at first glance.

Comment: I agree that you wrote the argument in a way that uses this, but it's not essential.  I mean to say:  there is a unique coset $g\langle c\rangle$ with $g c^{-1} g^{-1} = c$.  (Proof:  You showed existence.  If $g'$ also works, then $g c^{-1}g^{-1} = g'c^{-1}g^{\prime{-1}}$, so $g^{\prime{-1}}g$ centralises $c$, hence lies in $\langle c\rangle$.)  This unique coset consists of involution.

Comment: So now I'm more convinced than ever that this coset of involutions ought to have a name...

Comment: You could go the Banach route and pretend to modesty by calling them "involutions of type H".  Actually I see now on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space) that Fréchet named Banach spaces, and then Banach named Fréchet spaces.  So maybe we can make a deal that I will call these Hopkins involutions, and you can find something to name after me?  :-)

Comment: There's a unique plane where $c$ acts by rotation by $2\pi/h$, called the Coxeter plane. Maybe these $g$ act as reflections across a diameter in the Coxeter plane.

Comment: @SamHopkins, certainly $g$ preserves the Coxeter plane, and acts 'non-centrally' (since it doesn't commute with $c$).  Since it's an involution, it must have one eigenvalue $+1$ and one eigenvalue $-1$.  So it is as you [say](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379078/name-for-an-involution-associated-to-a-coxeter-element#comment962670_379078).

Comment: @SamHopkins I wanted to point out that, at least for Weyl groups, this is not _just_ a Coxeter element phenomenon. Every element $g\in W$ is conjugate to its inverse via an involution! This is a main result of Carter's "Conjugacy classes in the Weyl group", see Thm. C: (iii). So maybe you can call it something like "inverting involution" or "Carter's involution" etc. 
Carter's proof does involve special bipartite diagrams for all conjugacy classes, but you don't have something as nice as a Coxeter plane. Also, importantly, his proof is case-by-case. I do not think there is a uniform one.

Comment: Thanks for that context, @TheoDouvropoulos!

Comment: An involution w in W induces (by its action on the root datum) an involutive automorphism of the corresponding complex group G(C). It appears to be the case that the involutions having the given property with respect to a Coxeter element are the "principal" or "quasisplit" ones: the corresponding real form G(R) is the quasisplit one (in the equal rank inner class). Equivalently, principal means: there is a regular semisimple element in the Lie algebra in the -1 eigenspace of the involution. I don't know if this is helpful, nor do I have a decent proof.

Comment: @JeffreyAdams: certainly a more algebraic perspective is welcome as well! (By the way, are you aware that you have multiple MO accounts?- I think you are also https://mathoverflow.net/users/6030/jeffrey-adams)

Comment: Yes thanks, I learned recently I have multiplicity two, I have to resolve that.